# "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."

Tags: php

I am trying to use phpMailer to send confirmation messages to users via email. My code is this:

```
// smtp to send messages
$Email_Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //smtp host
$Email_Username = "******@gmail.com"; //email username
$Email_Password = "******87s"; // email password`
```

It was working, but now I get the message:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: provide code where you create PHPMailer object to send email

Comment: Add port

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Please go to your gmail account and select sign and security and on this option "Allow less secure apps": ON